# Double for..of loop into single line code

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make a one-line code from snippet below? Something like

```
Object.values(data).map(v=>v.map(v=>v.id))
```

```js
let div = document.getElementById("foo");

const data = {
  item: [ {id: 1} ],
  another: [ {id: 3}, {id: 10} ],
} 


let id = Object.values(data);
for(const foo of id){
  for(const bar of foo){
    div.append(bar.id + ", ") //instead div.append should be "return bar.id;"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Object.values(data).map(foo => foo.map(bar => bar.id));`?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @DanPrince it returns first level array :(; the result i get is [Array(100), Array(13), Array(40)]. The expected result is supposed to be all id values from Array(100), Array(13), Array(40) so it would be 153 id's returned | Edit: the id's from single line query are actually undefined aswell.

Comment: `.map()` is just a specialized `.reduce()`, so use `.reduce()` directly and build the final result: `Object.values(data).reduce((a,v)=>a.concat(v.map(v=>v.id)), [])`

Comment: Another way: `Object.values(data).reduce((a,v)=>[...a, ...v.map(v=>v.id)], [])`

Comment: @squint still didn't get how spread operator works, but once i get how it works i will consider that one during refactoring! Appreciate a lot for answers x)

Comment: Off Topic, but don't use things like `someNode.append()` or `someNode.innerHTML += ` repeatedly, like in a loop. Better accumulate the values in a String *(or in a documentFragment, if you're dealing with DOM Nodes)* and add them at once.

Comment: @Thomas used `.append()` only for snippet purpose to show visually example of received data x); nonetheless great advice for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to flatten the resulting array? In that case, you might try:

```
Object.values(data).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)).map(e => e.id)
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
const data = {
  item: [ {id: 1} ],
  another: [ {id: 3}, {id: 10} ]
} 

console.log(
  Object.values(data).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)).map(e => e.id)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
```

Comment: Indeed that was what I was lookin for, even tried with `Object.assign` :o

Comment: Glad that helped! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Please test this code for your 'bigger' arrays.

```js
let data = {item:[{id:1}],another:[{id:3},{id:10}]},
    result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(s, a) {
      s.push(data[a].map(v => v.id));
      return s;
    }, []);

    console.log([].concat.apply([], result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given two properties at object at Question you can use object destructuring, spread element

```js
const data = {
  item: [ {id: 1} ],
  another: [ {id: 3}, {id: 10} ],
} 

let ids = [...data.item, ...data.another].map(({id}) => id);

console.log(ids);
```